# How to guarantee that async method continuation runs on another thread?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, async-await

Does `ConfigureAwait(false)` guarantee that continuation runs on a different thread or only signals that  it's not compulsory to run on the same thread?

Is there any way to provide that guarantee?

I need to test context flow across threads.

Comment: The task may also complete synchronously on the same thread, in which case `ConfigureAwait(false)` simply does nothing. IMO, the easiest way to get the guarantee you're after is to use a custom awaiter (instead of `ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`).

Comment: @Noseratio Thanks for that comment. I completely forgot about this possibility.

Comment: No problem; overall, I wouldn't count count on `ConfigureAwait(false)` to be anything more than an optimization to avoid redundant context switching. Note what [MSDN docs say](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): *true to attempt to marshal the continuation back to the original context captured; otherwise, false.* Any other behavior beyond that statement would be undocumented and might be version-specific.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `ConfigureAwait(false)` tells the awaiter not to resume on the captured context and so the `SynchronizationContext` is ignored. That means that the continuation would be scheduled by the default `TaskScheduler` that uses `ThreadPool` threads.

If the original thread was a `ThreadPool` thread, the continuation **may** run on the same thread, otherwise your guaranteed it's a different thread.

You can start your test using a dedicated thread without a `SynchronizationContext` (or with `ConfigureAwait(false)`) to make sure the threads are different before and after the `async` operation.

Answer (score 0):

There's below scenario which `ConfigureAwait(false)` doesn't run a new context.

```
Task task2Seconds = Wait2Seconds();
Task task5Seconds = Wait5Seconds();

await task5Seconds;
await task2Seconds.ConfigureAwait(false);
```

The first `await` doesn't have that `ConfigureAwait(false)` but it takes longer than the second `await` who has that configure but be ready to resume in advance. So the second will resume on the same context.